# Real-time streaming using Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, processing, real-time

I am new to Apache Kafka, I went through a few basic Kafka with python projects. Most follow the same pattern of creating producer.py (inserts data into a topic) and consumer.py ( reads data from the subscribed topic) files. According to my understanding this is not real-time processing as the producer file is not reading the data continuously.

I wanted to know how can we use kafka+python for real-time streaming of data where the data is continuously fed into Kafka. ( One way I thought was to use a workflow tool like prefect or airflow and schedule it every few minutes, wanted to know if this is the correct approach.)

Ps: The project I am working on has the data source in form of REST API which is updated every few minutes. It would be helpful if you could guide me on how to use kafka+python in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka's strength is in being able to buffer the data received, in case the consumers are not ready, or are unable to handle the load at any point in time.  It *can* be as realtime as you want it to be, given proper server and client-side configuration (`linger.ms` is an important one here).

You don't specify what you consider as "real time", but typically, assuming there is data on the server side, and assuming the consumers are not lagging, you should get data on the consumer side within a second or less. Depending on your use case, this might be enough to consider it realtime, or it might be way too long.

If you use prefect or airflow, and schedule it every few minutes, that will *not* be a realtime solution.  You want a consumer that is always connected, 24/7, and is able to immediately respond the moment the server has additional data to serve.